# Bullet Physics Step Simulation Crash when maxSubSteps is not 0

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, irrlicht

I am using Bullet physics along with Irrlicht. My program consistently crashes when `maxSubSteps` is not set to zero when calling `stepSimulation`. I believe it has something to do with the time between the stepSimulation calls because when I stopped Irrlicht from drawing the scene, Bullet worked perfectly fine. Here is my `stepSimulation` call:

```
dynamics_world->stepSimulation(frame_delta_time, 0);
```

The segfault crashing does not occur when the `maxSubSteps` is zero. I would like to find a better solution to this as I have read that disabling substepping is experimental. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The parameters I am using when calling bullet's `stepSimulation()` are:

```
const irr::u32 then = device->getTimer()->getTime();
...
const irr::u32 now = device->getTimer()->getTime();
const irr::f32 frame_delta_time = (irr::f32)(now-then)/1000.f;
```

The value of `frame_delta_time` when the program crashes is 0.009. 
`fixedTimeStep` is the default 1/60.

Values other than 0 I have set `maxSubSteps` to are 1 (the default), 10 and 100.

The gdb stack trace indicates the program is crashing at releasePredivtiveContacts():

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  0x000055555557463b in btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::releasePredictiveContacts() ()
#1  0x00005555555746fc in btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::createPredictiveContacts(double) ()
#2  0x0000555555573c8f in btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::internalSingleStepSimulation(double) ()
#3  0x0000555555575335 in btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::stepSimulation(double, int, double) ()
```

**Edit:**
The full code is on Github: https://github.com/morgenm/PMC-Game/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by switching from the latest github code to the release code. When I posted this question I didn't realize I was using the latest github code.